# Python scipy.optimise.curve_fit gives linear fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have come across a problem when playing with the parameters of the curve_fit from scipy. I have initially copied the code suggested by the docs. I then changed the equation slightly and it was fine, but having increased the np.linspace, the whole prediction ended up being a straight line. Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(x, a, b, c):
    # This works fine on smaller numbers
    return (a - c) * np.exp(-x / b) + c


xdata = np.linspace(60, 3060, 200)
ydata = f(xdata, 100, 400, 20)

# noise
np.random.seed(1729)
ydata = ydata + np.random.normal(size=xdata.size) * 0.2

# graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, marker="o")
pred, covar = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, f(xdata, *pred), label="prediciton")
plt.show()
```

[image: Clear exponential gving a straight line fit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example code using your data and equation, with the initial parameter estimates given by scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm module. That module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, which requires bounds within which to search. In this example those bounds are taken from the data maximum and minimum values. It is much easier to supply *ranges* for the initial parameter estimates rather than specific values.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings


def func(x, a, b, c):
    return (a - c) * numpy.exp(-x / b) + c


xData = numpy.linspace(60, 3060, 200)
yData = func(xData, 100, 400, 20)

# noise
numpy.random.seed(1729)
yData = yData + numpy.random.normal(size=xData.size) * 0.2


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: `differential_evolution` itself is an optimization routine. You are using an optimization routine to find an initial guess for another optimization routine (`curve_fit`), which is fine, but isn't it a bit redundant? In the end, you still need some kind of initialization for the `differential_evolution`, by setting the bounds (which internally will be used by `differential_evolution` to set generate the guess), so why don't just set the guess based on the bounds anyway?

Comment: Because the bounds can be generous. Many combinations of data and equation are very sensitive to the specific initial parameter estimates, such that finding those initial values by hand is difficult. Finding generous *ranges* for the initial parameter estimates is usually much easier, no redundancy.

Comment: I think you are making a very broad statement that does not hold up in many situations in practice.  A generous bound, especially with a derivative-free routine like genetic, can find guess in ill-defined, slow-converging or even divergent region, just because it appears to be moderately good. A large range of bounds can also lead wasteful search. Global optimization is about balancing between exploration and local search. I leave the question of how to initiate the guess to the OP depending on the problem at hand. I avoid making broad statement of what should be the best way to initiate guess

Comment: In your answer to this question, you supply initial parameter estimates. How did you determine those estimates?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to start with a better guess, The default initial guess `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` seems to be in the divergent region.

I use the initial guess `p0 = (50,200,100)` and it works

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, marker="o")
pred, covar = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0 = (50,200,100))
plt.plot(xdata, f(xdata, *pred), label="prediciton")
plt.show()
```

[image: results]

Comment: In my answer below, I use scipy's implementation of the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to provide initial parameter estimates for curve_fit(). How did you determine the initial parameter estimates that you have used here in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a limitation of [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) which [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) uses by default. The good way to use it is to provide some decent initial guess for parameters before optimize. In my experiense this is particularly important when optimizing exponential functions like your example.  With such iterative algorithms as LM, the quality of your starting point determines that where the result will converge. The more parameters you have the more likely that your final result will converge to a completely unwanted curve. Overall the solution is finding a good initial guess somehow as other answers did.